# Decrease opacity of UIView in IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiview

I want to create an UIView user interface design with some transparency as i have mention in first image:

First Image :

[image]

here is my code :

```
self.view.opaque = NO;
self.activityIndicatorView3.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView3];
[self.activityIndicatorView3 startAnimating];

self.activityIndicatorView3.alpha = 1.0;
self.view.alpha = 0.15;
```

Using above code i am getting output as below output image :

[image]

here progress bar is not visible. I don't know, what i am doing wrong in my code. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: remove one line of code self.view.alpha = 0.15;

Comment: i can't remove this line, bcos am getting view background transparency using alpha 0.5. Thanks!

Comment: which is your view backgroundColor?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you added the activity indicator in View.So if your decreasing the alpha of view,It will effect to its subviews also.For this you can use

```
self.view.opaque = NO;
self.activityIndicatorView3.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView3];
[self.activityIndicatorView3 startAnimating];

self.activityIndicatorView3.alpha = 1.0;
self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
```

You can reduce the alpha of view background color .

Comment: @SivaprasadThanks, i have tried with self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6]; before.Using this code, its showing full black view background, but it should be transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the opacity for the superview will also affect its subviews.

The best way is to create a faded view for that effect

```
self.activityIndicatorView3.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView3];
[self.activityIndicatorView3 startAnimating];

self.activityIndicatorView3.alpha = 1.0;

// Change this self.view.alpha = 0.15; to following code

UIView *fadedView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [fadedView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [fadedView setAlpha:0.15];
    [self.view addSubview:fadedView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:fadedView];
```

Comment: Thanks, now i am getting progress bar visible using your code only backround is coming as fade white color, need to change it with black bg color.

Comment: I have two image for indicators, i am using third party library "TYMActivityIndicatorView".

Comment: you're saying that the faded view is remaining the same, ie white color can you produce screenshot? ...

Comment: Try  ///[self.view setBackground:]